# Alignment using secondary and tertiary features of DNA

Tags: sequence-alignment, phylogenetics

I m trying to align different sequences of length not greater than 50 bp. Could I incorporate additional information such as stacking energy, entropy, bonds etc as additional criteria in the alignment?

The sequences are very similar.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Did you some literature review? Which bonds are you referring to? Bonds between each pair of sequences? Or bonds within a sequence? I think it would be clearer if you explain what is your goal (and maybe it provides some key words to help find more information).